# svelte - Environment Variables not working

Tags: environment-variables, svelte

I am trying to set the env variables in my app using https://medium.com/dev-cafe/how-to-setup-env-variables-to-your-svelte-js-app-c1579430f032

```
import {config} from 'dotenv';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

plugins: [
        //Environment varialbes
        replace({
            // stringify the object       
            __myapp: JSON.stringify({
              env: {
                isProd: production,
                ...config().parsed // attached the .env config
              }
            }),
          }),
```

But when I try to access the env variables using "__myapp.env.API_ID", I get the following error in the dev tool - Uncaught Reference Error: __myapp is not defined"

Only way I could make it work is

```
import {config} from 'dotenv';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

config()

plugins: [
        //Environment varialbes
        replace({
            API_ID: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_ID)
          }),
```